# Xamarin iOS: Pass credentials over http

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to pass credentials over http on my xamarin iOS project but its not working.

```
public partial class WebView : UIViewController
{

        protected override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
         webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("https:example.com")));
         webView.AllowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true;
         webView.NavigationDelegate = new WebViewDelegate(this);
        }
}

public class WebViewDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate, INSUrlConnectionDataDelegate
    {

        public override void DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(WKWebView webView, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge, Action<NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSUrlCredential> completionHandler)
        {
            //base.DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge(webView, challenge, completionHandler);
            completionHandler(NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.PerformDefaultHandling, new NSUrlCredential("username", "password", NSUrlCredentialPersistence.ForSession));
            Console.WriteLine("We are authenticated");
            return;
        }
}
```

can anyone advise how to resolve this issue ?

**Update:**

DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge is being called and is being called continuously in a loop. Instead of getting the expected page , I am getting a blank page and it just says "Authenticate"

Comment: please define "not working".  Does it crash?  Is it giving an error?  Is it loading anything?  Does DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge ever get called?

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple's doc on [PerformDefaultHandling](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessionauthchallengedisposition):

> Use the default handling for the challenge as though this delegate method were not implemented. The provided credential parameter is ignored.

Try `UseCredential` instead:

```
var crendential = new NSUrlCredential("user", "pass", NSUrlCredentialPersistence.ForSession);

completionHandler(NSUrlSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, crendential);
```

Comment: 'DidReceiveAuthenticationChallenge' is being called in a loop infinite times and the web view now is just blank white screen.